# How to update global var in all components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I would like to be able to set up an automatic page title change system according to my loaded view.

First thought of using a global variable since the main.js :

```js
// MAIN.JS FILE
const App = createApp(AppVue).use(router)

App.config.globalProperties.$myGlobalVariable = "test"

App.mount('#app');
```

But, when I change the value in my component, it remains only local to this one

```js
// VIEW1.VUE
created() {
    this.$myGlobalVariable = "Compte utilisateur"
    console.log(this.$myGlobalVariable);
    // show "Compte utilisateur"
}

// VIEW2.VUE
created() {
    console.log(this.$myGlobalVariable);
    // show "test"
}
```

Comment: If you want to update global var in all components. Then you can change it's value globally. i.e. `App.config.globalProperties.$myGlobalVariable = "Compte utilisateur"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a reactive state in a composable.

```
const title = ref(''); // <=== outside of function scope

export function useTitle() {
  const setTitle = (newTitle) => {
    title.value = newTitle;
  };

  return { title, setTitle };
}
```

You can use it by `title` or update it by `setTitle` in any component.

For more resources.

https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I can't reload the value that I managed to change (changed well in the console.log)

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean by ` I can't reload the value that I managed to change`?

Comment: when i call the setter function in another component : import { useTitle } from '@/components/pageHeader/PageHeader.vue'; useTitle().setTitle("test2"); the value when i console.log(useTitle().title) = test2, but on my header title component the balise <h1>{{ title }}</h1> stay on test1 value and it's not updated.